# where to locate and add dojo toolkit to our project in worklight

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I have recently downloaded Worklight in Eclipe Juno SR2.I am creating a Hybrid App but cannot find option to add dojo toolkit anywhere like i had in the previous version of Worklight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Dojo Toolkit Support was checked when installing Worklight from the marketplace, when you create a Hybrid Application, click the button `Configure JavaScript Libraries...`. You should then be presented with a dialog with contents similar to previous versions of Worklight. Click `Add Dojo Toolkit` from there and click `Finish`.

After doing this, the wizard should update saying "Optional JavaScript Libraries: Dojo Toolkit".

See the following training modules:

- http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/03_03_Working_with_UI_frameworks.pdf
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html

Comment: @user3079154, please mark the question as Anwered. Also, this is mentioned in the documentation. Why not take the time and read it so you won't have to wait for other people to help you? http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/03_03_Working_with_UI_frameworks.pdf